# conda init error after fresh installation

Tags: conda, init

I installed conda on a new machine with ubuntu 22.04.

`conda activate` gives:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
```

After I type `conda init bash`, the following error appears.

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1132, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 69, in main_subshell
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 122, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_init.py", line 33, in execute
    return initialize(context.conda_prefix, selected_shells, for_user, args.system,
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 113, in initialize
    run_plan_elevated(plan2)
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 709, in run_plan_elevated
    result = subprocess_call(
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 98, in subprocess_call
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=stdin)
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1154, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/home/nd7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1985, in _communicate
    input_view = memoryview(self._input)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have tried `source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate`

PS: I also notice the "(base)" prefix in the terminal prompt is not there. But I have `auto_activate_base` set to be true.

Comment: Did you reload the shell or at least source the shell init file (`source ~/.bashrc`)? What terminal is being used?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I am using bash. I have seen a few people running into the same error 'TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'' but did not find a solution.

Comment: I realize that source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate solves the problem but I have to do it every time I start a new terminal.

Comment: What terminal is being used (bash is a shell, not a terminal)? For example, the VS Code terminal by default does not run user initialization scripts - it has to be configured to do so.

Comment: I run ps -p$PPID, it says gnome-terminal; I run ps -p $$, it says bash